# Is my proof that the relation ~ between pairs of integers is an equivalence relation correct?

Tags: real-analysis, relations, integers

since I havent written that many proofs before and because I am self studying, perhaps you could check if my proof works?

Let $\mathbb{Z}$* be $\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$ and $(x,y),(z,w),(u,v) \in \mathbb{Z} \times\mathbb{Z}$*.

Let the relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$* be defined as $(x,y)\sim(z,w)$ iff $xw=yz$. We seek to prove that $\sim$ is a transitive, symmetric and reflexive relation.

First we prove transitivity. Let $(x,y)\sim(z,w)$ and $(z,w)\sim(u,v)$. Then $xw=yz$ and $zv=wu$. It follows that $(xw)v = (yz)v$ and $y(zv) =
y(wu)$, which implies that $(xv)w = (yz)v$ and $(yz)v = (yu)w$, and hence $(xv)w = (yu)w.$ We know that $w \neq 0$, and therefore we deduce that $xv = yu$. It follows that $(x,y)\sim(u, v)$. Therefore$\sim$ is transitive.

Next we prove symmetry. Let $(x,y)\sim(z,w)$, then $xw=yz$. Rearranging, we get $zy=wx$, which implies that $(z,w)\sim(x,y)$.

Now we prove reflexivity. We note that $xy=yx$, so $(x,y)\sim(x,y)$. This concludes the proof.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. This is how you define fractions.